# Mathematica 10 not launching on Windows 8

Tags: front-end, windows

I have been using *Mathematica* 10.0.2 in my laptop with Windows 8 and it was working fine. One day I would try to open it as usual but it would not launch (I'd click at its icon in the start menu and absolutely nothing would happen, not even the kernel would start). However, in the task manager, *Mathematica* would appear in the list of "background processes".
I can open the *Mathematica* 10.0 kernel, though.

I tried to reinstall it, but the same problem remains. I also tried version 10.3 without success.
However, *Mathematica* 8.0 works fine (I would need a recent version though).

Could anyone help me solve this problem?
Many thanks.

Comment: No, the only process in the task manager is "Wolfram Mathematica 10.3" and it is in background processes.

Comment: No. I cannot expand it in the task manager, I'm afraid.

Comment: Not really. I am not sure I can do anything from the task manager. When I use Maple, for instance, I can find its processes both in the background and in the foreground (apps). But with Mathematica I can only find one in the background.

Comment: No, it does not. If I try to open notebook files, nothing happens (except adding a process in the task manager).

Comment: Technically yes, as I reinstalled it (and cannot start it). I do not even have the Base Directory and User Base Directory in my computer.

Comment: I had enabled hidden folders to be displayed and I really do not have these directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the default printer (Start menu -> Devices and Printers, right click on another printer and "set and default printer") then I restarted my computer. Now Mathematica 10.3 works.

I read somewhere else that changing the default printer could solve the problem but did not find any explanation why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart Print Spooler under Windows Servises. For me it works.